# implementing javascript callback with loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, rethinkdb

I am new to asynchronous programming and cant seem to solve this problem.
I am building this node.js app to serve stock quotes and basically what i need to do is query a database to get details of various companies. I need to send a request to api with company details as parameters which gives me the quote and then I need to update the database with new quote. So basically i need to do this for each company in the database. (I am using rethinkdb as my database)

This is my code

```js
query.companyList(function(err, data){
      if(err) {
         console.log(err);
      } 
      else {
        
        for(var i = 0;i < 6;i++){
           var comp = data.clist[i].exchange+ ':' +data.clist[i].ticker;
           console.log(comp);
           var cid = data.clist[i].id;
           console.log(cid);
           
           googleStocks([comp])
           .then(function(data){
             console.log((data[0].lt));
             r.table('company').get(parseInt(cid)).update({quote:{lastTradeTime:data[0].lt, lastTradePrice:data[0].l_cur, change:data[0].c, changePercent:data[0].cp}}).run()
             .then(function(results){
               console.log(results);
             })
             .catch(function(err){
               console.log(err);
             });
           })
           .catch(function(error){
             console.log(error);
           });
        }
      }
});
```

I know this is not an asynchronous code as the output of console.logs is pretty random.

So in short I need to send and API request and update the quotes for each company in my database.

My output:

Server started!
NASDAQ:MSFT
358464
NYSE:F
13606
NSE:TATAMOTORS
9708440
NASDAQ:FB
296878244325128
undefined:undefined
b90630ec-0a95-4373-93f8-2c36a336335d
NASDAQ:AAPL
22144
Webservice returned 400
Nov 8, 11:35AM EST
Nov 8, 3:50PM GMT+5:30
Nov 8, 11:35AM EST
Nov 8, 11:35AM EST
Nov 8, 11:35AM EST
{ deleted: 0,
  errors: 0,
  inserted: 0,
  replaced: 1,
  skipped: 0,
  unchanged: 0 }
{ deleted: 0,
  errors: 0,
  inserted: 0,
  replaced: 1,
  skipped: 0,
  unchanged: 0 }
{ deleted: 0,
  errors: 0,
  inserted: 0,
  replaced: 1,
  skipped: 0,
  unchanged: 0 }
{ deleted: 0,
  errors: 0,
  inserted: 0,
  replaced: 1,
  skipped: 0,
  unchanged: 0 }
{ deleted: 0,
  errors: 0,
  inserted: 0,
  replaced: 1,
  skipped: 0,
  unchanged: 0 }

Ignore "undefined:undefined" and "Webservice returned 400".

So what i would like to get for each company the status of update command

NASDAQ:MSFT
358464
{ deleted: 0,
  errors: 0,
  inserted: 0,
  replaced: 1,
  skipped: 0,
  unchanged: 0 }

I am sorry if I am not clear enough.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What's wrong with the code you've shown?

Comment: Can you share your code (attempting) to write in the database?

Comment: It is not asynchronous. The console log first prints all 5 id at once and then it send the api request by the time it is finished the value of i might be incremented several times. I might be wrong but I thinks this is what's happening.

Comment: @trincot r.table('company').get(parseInt(cid)).update({quote:{lastTradeTime:data[0].lt, lastTradePrice:data[0].l_cur, change:data[0].c, changePercent:data[0].cp}}).run()
             .then(function(results){
               console.log(results);
             })
             .catch(function(err){
               console.log(err);
             });

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add such information there?

Comment: BTW, your understanding of the term "asynchronous" seems incorrect. The `then` method is an implementation of a promise, and thus by definition asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
query.companyList(function(err, data){
      if(err) {
         console.log(err);
      } 
      else {

        for(var i = 0;i < 6;i++){
           var comp = data.clist[i].exchange+ ':' +data.clist[i].ticker;
           console.log(comp);
           var cid = data.clist[i].id;
           console.log(cid);
           (function(_id) {
               googleStocks([comp])
               .then(function(data){
                 console.log((data[0].lt));
                 r.table('company').get(parseInt(_id)).
                     update({quote:{lastTradeTime:data[0].lt,
                         lastTradePrice:data[0].l_cur, change:data[0].c, 
                             changePercent:data[0].cp}}).run()
                 .then(function(results){
                   console.log(results);
                 })
                 .catch(function(err){
                   console.log(err);
                 });
               })
               .catch(function(error){
                 console.log(error);
               });
            })(cid);
        }
      }
});
```

I did not run the code because I don't have the environment to.  But it should point you in the right direction.

Yes, what happens is the for loop will run six times and each time the async call is made.  By the time the result came back, the cid variable contains the last id and only the last id gets updated six times.

You enclosing the code block into an anonymous function and pass it cid, we ensure that the real id is used each time.